# Use putty on windows to connect to Cygwin on Windows10

Tags: ssh, putty, cygwin

Just got a shiny new laptop running Windows 10.  Installed Putty and installed Cygwin and now I want to setup Putty to open "Local" windows with a cygwin bash like I have with my last three laptops.  First (circa 2010) it was putty-cyg which is now unmaintained.  Then putty via telnet (circa 2015) but there is no telnet on Cygwin 64bit.

Now I see "Bare SSH connection" as the approved method per this post:

[https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/wishlist/cygwin-terminal-window.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/cygwin-terminal-window.html)

[https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.77/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-psusan](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/0.77/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-psusan)

The links mention a helper program **psusan** extracted from the 'unix' putty sourcecode.

There doesn't seem to be any binary "cygwin linked" psusan.exe program on the WWW so I downloaded the [putty 0.77 sourcecode](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/putty-0.77.tar.gz) to my cygwin install, compiled it in cygwin so that I have a psusan.exe executable on cygwin.

I am able to start psusan on cygwin with:

```
./psusan.exe                                # listens on stdin/stdout
or 
./psusan.exe --listen /path/to/socketfile   # creates a UNIX socketfile
```

And in the Putty 0.77 GUI I can say "Other -> Bare SSH Connection", but I can't find how to specify the socketfile (or maybe stdin/stdout??) in the GUI, or what to put in for "host" or "port" on the "session" page.

Lots of WWW searches later no real information on this procedure....I have temporarily solved it by starting a local openssh sshd on cygwin and then I can use the full SSH protocol to ssh into localhost:22.

Anybody have experience with this?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but the world has moved on.  You REALLY should try WSL1 (or 2).  WSL1 is *more like* running Cygwin only WAY WAY better.  You will be amazed.  I also don't see the point in SSHing into your own box using putty.  Why not just run bash?  I would love it if you can explain that to me.  I like to learn.  I am not criticizing.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas -- I am old....cygwin and PuTTY have admirably met my use cases for over a decade and while you can probably teach an old dog new tricks, it needs to be worth it.  I can't think of anything that I am missing in my cygwin/PuTTY setup, so perhaps ignorance is bliss.  I like PuTTY and the GUI it provides.  My basic requirement is that  I ONLY want one terminal emulator, so running cygwin bash or Windows CMD  or Powershell with their different cut/paste behaviours and other differences (font selection, background colors, etc) is undesirable.  I open a lot of PuTTY windows......

Comment: Why you are not using Mintty ? It is the default terminal on Cygwin for a reason

Comment: @matzen -- And that reason is? 

As stated above I use PuTTY.  One of the primary reasons is that I can, with a click on Desktop ShortCuts, open PuTTY windows to any of 30 different remote servers plus the very special "local" which is what I am asking about.  If I want to use mintty for everything I am not sure I can setup shortcuts to immediately open the BASH window and then SSH into remote servers as I can now do...even if I can setup those shortcuts, I would need a good reason to switch.  So far no reasons are compelling....

Comment: @DavidG you asked about a local terminal to open Bash. That is what Mintty does very well on Cygwin . As it is based on Putty , it should be similar to your experience on fully fledged Putty. http://mintty.github.io/ Otherwise stick to Putty and SSHD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simon Tatham, the author of PuTTY gave me the answer.  Here are the steps as I implemented to get PuTTY and Cygwin playing nicely.

1. Download and run the cygwin64 installer (setup_x86_64.exe) from https://cygwin.org/install.html
2. Add additional packages to install:  **cmake, gcc-core**.  These will pull in additional dependencies and are necessary to compile PuTTY to get the psusan.exe executable.
3. Download the PuTTY MSI Installer and install PuTTY.
   [https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest.html)
4. Download the PuTTY Source TARBALL :
   [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/putty-0.77.tar.gz](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/putty-0.77.tar.gz)
5. Unpack the tarball and compile:

> ```
> tar -zxvf putty-0.77.tar.gz
> cd putty-0.77
> cmake .
> cmake --build .
> ```

6. You should now have a file psusan.exe.  Install that in Cygwin:

> ```
> cp psusan.exe /cygdrive/c/cygwin64/bin/psusan.exe
> ```

7. Now Configure PuTTY.  Open the "New Session" and click on the Connection -> Proxy tab.  In that tab set "Local Proxy" and add the command:

> ```
> C:\cygwin64\bin\psusan.exe --sessiondir /home/mydir
> ```

/home/mydir is where the session will open

[image: Proxy tab]

8. Now go to the "Session" tab and save the session:

Change connection type to "Bare SSH Connection"
Enter whatever you want for hostname and saved sessions (I entered 'cygwin') and click "Save".

[image: Session Tab]

Now click "Open" and Profit!